# Upload folder with subfolders containing files

Tags: internet, directory, upload

I am new to ubuntu. Ubuntu caught my attention, because I tried to send a bigger attachment via Thunderbird.

Now I want to upload a folder containing subfolders containing 216 files, overall 1,57 GB of data. I seem to be able to directly upload single files via the internet (browser: Firefox 21.0) interface but not folders with content.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your support
HJStern

Comment: What is the target system? Does it support any file transfer protocol? Please add those information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a folder as an attachment. The best way is to archive the folder so it becomes a single file. You can use Archive Manager or go to the parent folder containing the folder you want to upload, right click on it and select Compress...

Answer (score 0):

There are a several options for copying files. Which one you use depends on your requirements and preference.

If you are trying to share a large file with another person (or multiple people), the simplest solution may be to use a bittorrent client (Transmission may be installed on your system already) to create and share a torrent of the files. It would be a good idea to compress the files first as user160222 suggested.

Look into setting up an ftp server if you want to create a directory of files to be allow ongoing access to remote users.

If you have shell (SSH) access to the local and remote machines, you can use scp with the option to recursively copy directories and their contents.